# CPPCoreGuidelines span<T> for a T** interface?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

In digital signal processing audio is commonly passed around as a 2D array of channels and samples i.e.

```
void use(float** buffer, int channels, int samples) { ... }
```

A lot of libraries I use expect this format.

In terms of my own code, for safer manipulation, is there a way I could use `gsl::span<T>` to set up views on these buffers?

(I understand 1D but I'm not sure how I would set up for a 2D `float**` array)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same way you'd do it for std::vector, consider a `span<span<float>>`

Comment: @HansPassant, As far as I was aware, there's no easy way of going from `vector<vector<T>>` to `T**` - `data` will give you a pointer to a bunch of vectors, whereas the API expects contiguous elements across inner vectors. That's not to say `span` has the same problem (I don't know if it's designed with that in mind).

Comment: Off topic: "A lot of libraries I use expect this format" actually, you will find that a lot of other libraries will unroll the the 2D array[m][n] into a 1D array[m*n]. It's easier to create, destroy, and pass around and often gives a performance boost by forcing all of the data to stay in one block of memory.

Comment: Use `gsl::multispan` (not well documented)

Comment: @HansPassant that was what I first thought. But I'm not sure how to make one. Say I have an existing float buffer, 2 channels, 512 samples long, first make the inner span<float>'s for each channel `span<float> L (buffer[0], 512); span<float> R {buffer[1], 512}` ...I don't understand what to do next?

Comment: @Galik this looks interesting although all I can find is the source from Microsoft GSL, I find it hard to figure out? I can see the constructors marked multidimensional. Also I'm restricted to using [gsl lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/gsl-lite) right now which doesn't have multi_span